# Iimport data in Matlab from Excel with string label

Tags: matlab, import, import-from-excel

I am new in Matlab and I want to import an Excel file in matrix format. My columns are all numerical except the last column, which is a string and it's my labels. When I import my data set Matlab says that label column is unimportable and replaces it to zero! How can I do about it?

Comment: Please post the code you're using, and the specific error you get

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code:

```
[num, txt, raw] = xlsread(excelpath, sheetname, A00:C20)
```

Excep path, sheetname and A00:C20 are arbitrary. You can find table containing all items in specified cells in **raw** variable. **num** contains numeric values and **txt** contains string values.